# Create wireframe of model in threes.js GLTFloader

Tags: three.js

I want to load a 3D model and create the wireframe in threejs. How may I achieve this effect? Thank you very much.

This is the code I have for now, but it doesn't work.

```
var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
loader.load('name.gltf', function(geometry, materials) {
    var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial();
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    group = new THREE.Object3D();
    group.add(mesh); 
    scene.add(group); 
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [GLTFLoader docs](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/loaders/GLTFLoader), the callback's argument is an object with a `.scene` property containing your model. Like any nested three.js object, you can modify materials using `.traverse()`.

```
var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
loader.load('name.gltf', function(gltf) {
    var object = gltf.scene;
    object.traverse((node) => {
      if (!node.isMesh) return;
      node.material.wireframe = true;
    });
    scene.add(object);
});
```

Comment: I would suggest removing `node.material.needsUpdate = true;` from this answer.

Answer (score -2):

var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({wireframe:true});

Comment: It keep showing TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'sphere.center') in the console. I don't have any idea about this error.

Comment: The GLTF loader loaded callback isn't structured like the other loaders...

It recieves a single object that contains a scene and other parts of the exported data.

You're going to have to  get the .scene from that object, and .traverse() it to find the meshes you want.. then add them to the scene like your doing.

For problems like this, use Chrome debugger to set a breakpoint then hover over the values and inspect them to see why they are wrong :)
Check out this:
https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/loaders/GLTFLoader

Comment: I can use other loader as well. Which loader is best to use in this case? Thank you so much.

Comment: Thank you very much. I got it working by tracing the GLTF file path and find the right geometry.